# Is there a way to call the field of a derived type using a string?

Tags: fortran

Is there a way to call the field of a derived type via string argument in fortran?

something like...

```
subroutine set(car, fieldName, value)
    type(Car_T) :: car
    character*(*) :: fieldName
    character*(*) :: value

    car%[fieldName] = value
end subroutine set
```

I know you can do stuff like this in javascript, c#, ect., but this could really help me from having a ton of duplicate code if fortran allows it.

Comment: Seems like you may want to use an associative array and not derived type components.

Comment: Any recommendations for associative arrays in Fortran? I've used Judy arrays (http://judy.sourceforge.net/) and otherwise self-implemented stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar with namelists but it is for items known to the program: not new items.

```
integer:: inin
real:: rere
namelist /info/ inin, rere

inin = 0 ! default
rere = 20.4 ! default
read (*, nml=info)
print *, 'inin=', inin
print *, 'rere=', rere

stop
end
```

On the input

```
&info inin=2 rere=40.0 /
```

Or if you wish to input one value only

```
&info rere=3.162 /
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I wanted it to, but by making it read a string instead of stdin I was able to do it. Thanks for reminding me of this.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You will need to write the executable code (perhaps a SELECT CASE construct) that maps the value of the string across to the relevant component.

You only need to write this once for each unique set of component names.

Comment: That is the way I was currently thinking of doing it, but there are several different types of file inputs and can be in a few different sub types, so I would have to write a lot of code that does very similar things multiple times. Not my original code, but I'm doing the best I can with it.